# CSS: dynamic width div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a slider and I have problems with the stylying of the container.

I have 3 `div`:

1. A `div` that sets the width and height of the slider
2. A container `div` with all the content divs (and the scroll for the slider)
3. Many `div`that show different contents each

What I want to do is apply a negative margin on the second div to slide the content.

LIVE example: http://jsbin.com/efuyix/7/edit

JS:

```
  function animate(element) {
  var start = new Date();
  var id = setInterval(function() {
    var timePassed = new Date() - start;
    var progress = timePassed / 600;
    if (progress > 1) progress = 1;
    element.style.marginLeft = -50 * Math.pow(progress, 5)+"px";
    if (progress == 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

CSS

```
  .example_path {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .example_block {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
   }
  .example_in_block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
   }
```

HTML

```
<div class="example_path">
  <div class="example_block" onclick="animate(this)">
    <div class="example_in_block" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="example_in_block" style="background-color:pink;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***The problem:***
The width of `.example_block` has to be exactly the same or more than (amount of content divs `.example_block` * 50 [width size of content div] ) to work.

For example, if I set the width size of the `.example_block` to 90, the pink div will be below the blue div and not beside it.

I want the container div to be dynamic so I don't have to set the specific width size.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please briefly tell ehat you want to do with the div's (as in how you want it to be dynamic - are you gonna change the width by javascript of both div's?)

Comment: @tunetosuraj you can see how it's dont in the live example i gave in the top of the topic , i want to change the container margin to negative margin

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the float:left in the .example_block.

See http://jsbin.com/efuyix/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

Not with negative margins. You can probably set padding on one of the outer DIVs.

Also, min-width isn't going to be backwards compatible with older versions of IE.

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5xBYN/6/

If the initial positioning is good, you can then use negative values on your container DIV (the third DIV) for top, left, right or bottom to achieve sliding.

Update:

Maybe this is closer to what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/5xBYN/7/

I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe edit the fiddle I posted and update your question with what I'm getting wrong if there is anything.

Comment: the second div is the container (example_block class)